# Write to all file matches in find command

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-findutils

I want to echo some text into all file matches with the **find command** in linux shell. I tried this" 
`find . -type f -name "file*.txt" -exec echo "some text" > - '{}' ';'` But this does not work.Is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command did not work because `>` is interpreted by shells like `sh` or `bash`. When using `find -exec echo` only `echo` is started. There is no shell that could interpret the `>` as redirection.

Note that `>` *over*writes files. You probably wanted to *append*. Use `>>` to do so.

```
find . -type f -name 'file*.txt' -exec sh -c 'echo "some text" >> "$0"' {} \;
```